# WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com/socket.io/1/websocket/6CFI8y7Ls3LgCqLCeX5k' failed

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I wanted to test the server on a VPS. I'm using `Express.io` in background. There is no problem in `localhost` but in VPS I'm getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com/socket.io/1/websocket/6CFI8y7Ls3LgCqLCeX5k' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 520
```

I'm able to send/get data with `socket.io` but this needs to fixed. What can be cause to this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a configuration issue with your VPS. You may not be able to fix it, or you may need to get support directly from your VPS provider. Your server appears to drop websocket connections, but socket.io falls back to HTTP long-polling or Flash sockets. Do you simply want to get rid of the error, or is it important to you that socket.io run on webscokets (e.g., because long-polling is too slow for your needs)?

Comment: I've used same VPS before but this problem is happening now, VPS is in DigitalOcean. I want to get rid of this error, thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have logged ticket to their support desk to try to pin point the cause, most likely their configuration.